# Replace model in afterModel

Tags: ember.js

How does one replace the route/controller's model in the afterModel hook.

[here is a jsbin of things I've tried](http://jsbin.com/goqiz/3/edit)

```
afterModel: function(model){
  model = { id: "noob", name: "Bob" }; 
  this.currentModel = { id: "noob", name: "Bob" };
  //this.set('controller.content', { id: "noob", name: "Bob" });
  //this.set('controller.model', { id: "noob", name: "Bob" });
  this.set('currentModel', { id: "noob", name: "Bob" });
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) { resolve({ id: "noob", name: "Bob" });          
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not change the `model` for `Ember.Route#setupController()` in the `afterModel` hook, as

> This method is called with the controller for the current route and the model supplied by the model hook. (Ember Documenation over [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController))

why do you want to change your model after it was resolved?

Comment: Thanks for that you may be right - I'll leave this open for a couple of days in case someone has a different idea.  The model hook is not always called and I need somewhere to always execute model logic.

Comment: @TrevTheDev do you have any chance to execute your model logic in `setupController`?